# What does the of() method mean? Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Sorry for the stupid question but upon reading about ViewModel i came across

```
randomViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(RandomViewModel::class.java)
```

I just want to know what the of() is in general. Is it just a function used by the providers? Or is it a special operator?

Thanks

Comment: It's a function in ViewModelProviders class which takes `fragment` or `FragmentActivity` as its parameter.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders#of_1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Deprecated
    @NonNull
    @MainThread
    public static ViewModelProvider of(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
        return new ViewModelProvider(fragment);
    }
```

As we can see by viewing the source code of ViewModelProviders, of() is basically an extension function of ViewModelProvider that returns a new NonNull ViewModelProvider object with the parameter fragment/activity and locks it on the MainThread. Basically it's a fancy way of writing ViewModelProvider(fragment) with extra steps.

But be aware that of() is deprecated, you now initialise a ViewModel like this:

```
ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(),ViewModelFactory(Database.getDatabase(requireActivity()))).get(ViewModelClass::class.java)
```

Comment: i see “of” being used everywhere especially in flutter providers. So i thought it was an operator. Thank you for helping me understand and learn.

Answer (score 1):

> ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(RandomViewModel::class.java)

```
ViewModelProviders.of(this)
```

It is a static function that takes current context to retain the ViewModel scope. In `this` case Current activity is gonna be the context for which ViewModel scope will be retained.

```
.get(ViewModel::class)
```

It does two things

1. If the ViewModel is available it will return the ViewModel instance.
2. Otherwise, it will create and return the new instance.

Answer (score 1):

The `of()` method here is a method inside the  `ViewModelProviders` class which just creates a `ViewModelProvider` object, which retains `ViewModels` while the scope you have given eg Activity, Fragment is alive.